# How to Plot a graph with respect to time

Tags: plotting, physics

[image]

I am new to wolfram Mathematica. Can someone please assist by showing me how I can plot “d” shown in The screenshot with respect to time, graphically?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. Please, do not post your code as a screenshot. Instead, copy it directly from Mathematica and paste it into your question.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Plot`.

Comment: Plot[d, {t, 0, 10}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find the answer in the [Wolfram Language documentation center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). Note that you can make $d$ a function by defining $d[t\_]=``rhs''$. After doing this definition, you can use the function `Plot[]`. You have access to the Wolfram Language documentation center by pressing `F1` in the Mathematica.